# Setting up page dimensions in LaTeX

Tags: margins, geometry

I generally try typeset a document in LaTeX and then take a print out. Since I am not familiar with setting up the page dimensions, when I take print out on an A4 paper, lot of gaps are left.

- So can anyone tell me how I should go about defining the commands so that a gap of 1 inch is left from each corner of the A4page

Comment: This is a job for the `geometry` package. But, it's lunch time here.

Comment: @kan: http://www.xkcd.com/1201/

Comment: @RyanReich :)  LOL, it was one more line. I wish I said it explicitly. I was very hungry, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package is all you need for this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy text.

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

See the [documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) for further tweaking of the doc­u­ment di­men­sions.